# using curl in rails 3 controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here, I want to import database from different source, with some api like this:

```
curl -H X-Auth-Ticket:47827EC1B6871D... https://url/10482/ApiGetDeepData | gzip -d >result.json
```

Now, this command will export the curl result into json file and I need a way to import those json data to my rails 3 database. For that I need help to import json file into my rails 3 database. which I don't know

If any one knows how to write curl in controller, I will really appreciate it.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use httparty for the api call using post, get etc.

```
response = HTTParty.post(
  "https://url/id/ApiGetDeepData", 
  headers: {"Auth-Ticket" => 47827EC1B6871D...}
)
```

In this way no need to export any json file, you will directly get the response in json format and you can export any of the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we don't write curl inside rails controller. I use [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) which is a simple Rest client for Rails.

And the way to use curl is to put the command inside **``**

Example:

```
`curl http://somedomain/url`
```

Comment: Would appreciate to accept the Answer or Vote up if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I got system() function in ruby that will execute the curl command in controller also, but I am unable to access the result by key to fetch value of the key,  Can you help me on this?

Comment: If system() works fine, you can post it as an answer. Sure I can help with fetching the values. You can post it as a question.

Comment: @przbadu I am pretty sure `system()` returns `true` if the command runs and `false` if it doesn't. It will not give you your results like the back-tick solution Srikanth posted.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, using HTTParty we can easily fetch the api datas.

```
response = HTTParty.post("url_to_my_api", body: { signinEmail: ENV["EMAIL"], password: ENV["PASSWORD"] }
)

result = HTTParty.post(
  "url_to_my_api", 
  headers: {"Auth-Ticket" => response["ticket"]}
)
```

and this really helps me.

Edit:
corrected syntax